# ¿Cómo hacer que mediante una combinación de teclas un usuario pueda abrir una sección privada?

Tags: javascript

Se me ha ocurrido una idea un poco loca pero no se si se puede hacer. Quisiera saber si se puede programar que un usuario estando en una web, pueda abrir una sección privada solo con la combinación de dos teclas por ejemplo: `ctrl+a`. Así por ejemplo mis clientes podrían abrir un login sin que este estuviera especificado en la web de forma visible.

Sería entonces que lo que se abre es un archivo de nombre por ejemplo loginclients.php o un html o una ruta del tipo http://etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías usar la librería [jQuery.Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) que permite capturar eventos del teclado.

Podrías hacer algo así:

```js
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+a', function(){
  //alert("Has pulsado ctrl+a");
  var win = window.open("https://www.google.com", '_blank');
  win.focus();
});

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+l', function(){
  alert("Has pulsado ctrl+l");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Teclado Shortcuts</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/master/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ejecuta el código y da click en la region donde se ejecuta el script, luego presiona `ctrl+a` o `ctrl+l` y se lanzará un `alert()` diciendo que tecla pulsaste, es un ejemplo básico pero espero te sirva.

Para ver el script que abre una nueva pestaña, funcionando correctamente te dejo un jsbin en el siguiente Link http://jsbin.com/fetedifune/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Gracias Juan, Creo que por ahora es la mejor respuesta, pues muestra código que se puede ejecutar y probar en SOes. Quisiera que se pudiera en lugar de abrir una alerta que se me abra una pestaña nueva que sea un archivo o html o php para que no lo tengas que crear puedes poner una url. http://... ¿puedes hacer ese cambio?

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, revisala y considera marcarla como solucion a tu pregunta, asi otros usuarios pueden encontrarla util.

Comment: Siempre lo hago no te preocupes. Lo único que solo trabajo por las mañanas. No podré revisarlo hasta mañana. Gracias.

Comment: Ok, los snippets de stackoverflow no permiten abrir nuevas pestañas, por ese motivc te aparecerá un error en el script anterior, para ver su correcto funcionamiento te dejo el siguiente link a jsbin http://jsbin.com/fetedifune/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

Lo que comentas se puede conseguir con JavaScript, (aunque no lo he probado) quizás algo así te funcione:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 40) {
    // to do...
  }
}, false)
```

En cualquier caso hay algunas librerías para ello, te dejo unos links:

- [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice)
- [Shortcuts Library](http://www.stepanreznikov.com/js-shortcuts/)
- [keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster)
- [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer lo puedes sacar de aqui:
http://www.aprenderaprogramar.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=844:capturar-eventos-de-teclado-javascript-tecla-pulsada-fromcharcode-keycode-wich-alt-ejemplos-cu01161e&catid=78:tutorial-basico-programador-web-javascript-desde-&Itemid=206

1-lo primero deberías capturar las teclas que presiona el usuario y después con un if controlas que haga lo que tu quieras que muestre,(esto lo puedes conseguir con la propiedad hidden de javascript si no recuerdo mal).

2-la idea no es mala pero al usuario no le hagas aprenderse teclas raras para logearse porque nunca sabe uno que tipo de conocimientos tienen sus usuarios y como les resulte difícil se van a otra web.

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score -1):

Hace unos años, hubo un huevo de pascua en muchas web, que presionando una serie de teclas, se activaba. Quizás podrias seguir esa misma estrategia para lo que quieres hacer.

Dale un vistazo a [konami-js](http://code.snaptortoise.com/konami-js/) para reutilizar lo que hay ahí y no reinventes la rueda :-D

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio rfrp. Tu iniciativa es muy buena. Tal como está tu publicación ahora, luce más como un comentario. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y edita la publicación para que pueda proveer una respuesta al usuario y para que quede para la posteridad. Por ejemplo, podrías poner un ejemplo para usar esta librería konami-js para resolver el problema del autor.