# ¿Cómo enviar formulario HTML con una combinación de teclas?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, onclick

Tengo un formulario, el cual lleva en conjunto un `onclick` de javascript, lo que quiero es que si el usuario por ejemplo hace la combinación de teclas <kbd>Crtl+S</kbd>, fse realize la acción de como si diera click a enviar

**EDICIÓN**: Por si sirve para darme una ayuda, el inicio del formulario

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Podrias añadir algo mas del codigo que has conseguido

Comment: Hay una pregunta similar que contiene la solución, revisa el link:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23900/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-que-mediante-una-combinaci%C3%B3n-de-teclas-un-usuario-pueda-abrir-una-se

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery) la pregunta equivalente en inglés

Comment: @ChristianCuadrosBetancur No, esa no es la solución, un sitio que tiene lo que quiero llegar a lograr es https://hastebin.com , aquí escribes un texto y das Control + S y se envía el form, pero yo puse vuestras respuestas y tu link y nada funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregas un listener y verificas si las teclas presionadas corresponden a las que deseas.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  var keyCode = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(e.ctrlKey && keyCode === 83) {
  e.preventDefault();
  enviar.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="alert('Enviado!')"/>
```

Comment: Justo acabo de mirar tu respuesta y ¡he visto que funciona! Gracias, creo que te verificare porque tu solución ocupa menos bytes en el documento que la que escribí yo

Comment: Que bueno que te sirva, de nada

Answer (score 2):

¿Porque me autorespondo?

Como ninguna respuesta me ayudó a solucionar mi problema, he estado bastante tiempo buscando por internet, y he encontrado la solución correcta a mi problema:

No marco ningun *Verified*, porque probé los links o soluciones dadas y ninguna me funciona

```
<script>
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    var key = undefined;
    var possible = [ e.key, e.keyIdentifier, e.keyCode, e.which ];

    while (key === undefined && possible.length > 0)
    {
        key = possible.pop();
    }

    if (key && (key == '115' || key == '83' ) && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && !(e.altKey))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById( "id de boton submit" ).click();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}); 
</script>
```

Esto me funciona, dando a <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> y me envía al **upload.php** y si que revisa el `validateForm()`

Answer (score 0):

Aunque como te comentan hay una pregunta similar cuya respuesta propone utilizar un plugin de jQuery, esto también se puede hacer sin utilizar ninguna librería.

Cuidado con la combinación de teclas que eliges. Ctrl+S, por ejemplo, la captura Chrome para permitir al usuario guardar la página actual en un fichero html.

He preparado un ejemplo utilizando Ctrl+I.

Según lo que quieras conseguir podrías hacer `submit` directamente del `form` para lo que tendrías que ejecutar tú mismo la función de validación:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', checkHotkeys);

function checkHotkeys(e){
  if (e.code === 'KeyI' && e.ctrlKey){
    if (validateForm())
      document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }
}

function validateForm(){
  console.log('validateForm llamado');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

O provocar un click sobre el botón `submit` con lo que se ejecutaría la función asociada al `onsubmit`:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', checkHotkeys);

function checkHotkeys(e){
  if (e.code === 'KeyI' && e.ctrlKey){
    document.getElementById('submitButton').click();
  }
}

function validateForm(){
  console.log('validateForm llamado');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ponerle el evento a la pagina para la combinación y así sabría que debe enviar el formulario, seria así:

```
$(document).keydown(function (ev) {
            if (ev.keyCode == 17) { //al presionar Ctrl(17) ,preguntaría  si luego se presiona nuevamente por ejemplo A
                $(document).keydown(function (ev) {

                   if (ev.keyCode == 65) { //al presionar A(65)
                     $('#id_formulario').submit() //al producirse la combinación se envía el formulario
                      return false;
                   }

                });
            } 
    });
```

Este código respondería a la combinación Ctrl-A.

Te dejo los códigos para que elijas la combinación con el código que desees

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y espero te resuelva.

Comment: No me parece una buena solución, tendrías que desactivar el segundo listener cuando Ctrl se deje de pulsar (onkeyup), complicando mucho código

Comment: de esta manera igual funciona , edita el código , cambia el submit , por un alert('hola mundo') y veras que funciona, las en las combinaciones de tecla , ambas teclas se mantienen en keydown, y se lanza la acción cuando ocurren ambas presiones de las teclas

Comment: Funcionar funciona, pero ¿qué pasa si realizas esa acción y luego pulsas sin usar Ctrl?

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, ya me di cuenta donde radicaba el error y por que la necesidad del keyup.